# How to assign number to rectangle painted on panel

Tags: c#, panel, drawrectangle, paintevent

Can I assign integer value to rectangles drawn on panel in paint event?

I have a List that I loop through ... I would like to assign an integer value to each rectangle

Later when a user clicks on one of the rectangles, that integer value will be used to delete one of the points from List

Then the panel will be refreshed ... thus, deleting that rectangle

Comment: You colud change the List<Rectangle>  to a Dictionary<int, Rectangle> ! But you also need to understand that the Rectangles you draw are only pixels and do not have a life of their own outside of the list; so __you can't really click them__, you only click on pixels and will need to __search__ through the list to find the right one! If they don't overlap Rectangle.Contains e.Location in the MouseClick event will help.. The number won't really help

Comment: As I said, you can't click on the rectangles, only on pixels! the drawn rectangles are no objects!!

Comment: OK. If you run into trouble update the question to include the code that won't work as intended and I'll have a look..!